# Automatic Staging with Git

Tags: git

I have a git repository and it is doing something I've never seen before and haven't found a solution anywhere. I initialized with `git init` and added everything with `git add *` and went on my way now when I try to commit after editing any number of files none are staged for commit so I have to do `git add -A` which then stages them all for a commit. Is there a way to skip the `git add -A` step? I have used git with Xcode a lot and never have had to move them from not staged to staged while in the terminal.

Is there a paradigm to the git staging area I am missing? How are you supposed to use it?

Comment: You may find the answers to the following question of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834627/disable-git-staging-area

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You do have to add your changes to the commit, but you can just use:

```
git commit -a
```

To add your changes AND commit or

```
git commit -am 'commit message'
```

Which is how i usually roll.

Manually adding your changes lets you not commit everything if you dont want to, which I'm sure you can tell is useful sometimes.

Comment: will `git commit -a` only commit the changed files or will it also include the untracked files? If it is the former, how can I have it automatically commit untracked files as well?

Comment: It seems odd that the default behavior is to consider use cases when you don't want to track everything. In most cases, wouldn't you want to track everything?

Answer (score 2):

Add an alias which will do the add and the commit for you and start using the alias. If you are on Windows, I would have suggested TortoiseGit, which abstracts out the index.

Answer (score 2):

In case of git you don't need to add files. Git keeps a track of all the files that have been added by you till till now. You only need to add if you are adding a new file that is not there in your git remote repo.

For files that have been modified, you can use git commit -am "message"

git commit -am "message" will automatically commit all the changed files.

After a commit you need to push the data to remote using git push command.

Hope this resolves your problem!!